# Counting unions of unlabelled connected graphs

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, enumerative-combinatorics, generating-functions

My question can be stated as follows: let $X$ be a hereditary family of unlabelled graphs closed under disjoint unions. Suppose we know, for each $n$, the number $c_n$ of **connected** graphs in X on $n$ vertices. How do we get from that the **total** number $x_n$ of graphs in $X$ on $n$ vertices?

I am vaguely aware that there are methods involving generating functions that answer (some version of) this question, but the only source I found for that online is a transcription of a set of lecture notes with no references whatsoever. I am not particularly well versed in the theory of generating functions, so any source which goes from the basics to the relevant derivation would be greatly appreciated.

However, if it is at all possible, I would ideally like to find an explicit formula for the coefficients $x_n$ in terms of the $c_i$, or at least a (tight-ish) lower bound for $x_n$ in terms of the $c_i$.

I can see the answer in some very simple cases: if, say, $c_i = 1$ for all $i$ (e.g., $X$ is the class of unions of cliques), then $x_n$ is just the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)) $p(n)$ from number theory (compare this to the labelled case, where we get the [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number)). However, I do not see how to generalise this. It seems to me very likely that this question would have been studied in the language of multisets, but once again, I am not particularly familiar with that area.

Comment: This is what exponential generating functions do. If you want an online source see e.g. Section 2.3 of these note: https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.2562.

Comment: Exponential generating functions are for labeled graphs. For unlabeled graphs you need ordinary generating functions. If $c_n$ is the number of unlabeled connected graphs in $X$ on $n$ vertices then the generating function for all unlabeled graphs in $X$ is 
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-x^n)^{-c_n}=\exp\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^\infty c(x^i)/i\biggr)$$
where $c(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n x^n$. The first formula is easier to see but the second is usually more useful for computations. This is well known, and may have been first found by Pólya.

Comment: Apologies, Ira is of course correct, I missed the unlabeled nature of the question. (I'll leave a link to those notes of Ardila because they're very good, anyways.)

Comment: One online reference is Flajolet and Sedgewick, http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf, page 34.